# How do you separate jekyll site content and code into separate branches?

Tags: web, jekyll, github-pages

Hi I am using jekyll hosted on github oages and I would like to separate the content and code of my site into separate branches so:

1. It is more organised.
2. If I want to change some code in the site experimentally I can create A new branch based of the code branch and I don't have to worry about updating its contents when I create new blogs in my main code branch.
   I have done some research someone mentioned using gem files to store the code but creating a jekyll theme and distributing it with ruby gem seems a daunting task since I don't even know the gem programming language.

Any thoughts? And thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a CI solution.

[Github Action](https://docs.github.com/actions) should be a good choice to you since you are using Github Pages.

To simplify the process, you could leverage [jekyll-deploy-action](https://github.com/jeffreytse/jekyll-deploy-action).
It also makes the plugins those are not on the [Github Safe List](https://pages.github.com/versions/) works on Github Pages.

To achieve this, just follow the [usage doc](https://github.com/jeffreytse/jekyll-deploy-action#-usage).

Answer (score 0):

Should have said this earlier but I found a solution to the problem you can actually set a them variable in you _config.yml so it pilots to a GitHub repo

Answer (score 0):

To seperate the (markdown) content from the (template) code you should use/create a theme.